# With what can I replace this for loop so my Arduino doesn't spit jibberish?

Tags: programming, c, signal-processing

I have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (DELAY_SIZE - 1); i++) {
   if (check_tag_in_char(delay_chars[i], BOOK_UPLOAD_END_TAG)) {
       tag_pos = 0;
       Serial.println("Uploaded");
       is_uploading_book = false;
   }
}
```

where

```
#define DELAY_SIZE 50
const char* BOOK_UPLOAD_END_TAG = "(__BOOK_UPLOAD_END__)";
char delay_chars[DELAY_SIZE];

int check_tag_in_chars(char a, const char* TAG_STR) {
   if (a == TAG_STR[tag_pos]) { tag_pos++; } else if (a == TAG_STR[0]) { tag_pos = 1; } else { tag_pos = 0; }
   if (TAG_STR[tag_pos] == '\0') {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

The for loop above with the check_tag_in_chars check seems to make my Arduino spit jibberish on Serial.write() (which you can see in the full code).
I suppose the for loop is somehow overloading the Arduino.
The Serial.write() starts normal and then turns into jibberish like that:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla est purus, ultrices in porttitor 
>   in, accus⸮o⸮a⸮a⸮nct⸮oto⸮ou⸮ubt⸮ue⸮tl⸮ei⸮at⸮e⸮i⸮rm⸮⸮tlu⸮or⸮tatcsu⸮om⸮lu⸮oaess⸮vi⸮pdteea⸮aestp⸮r⸮tda⸮lcp⸮ddt⸮ir⸮eo⸮oe⸮i⸮g⸮u⸮aacdeu⸮bt.Qiu⸮pdtiu⸮l
>   g⸮ie⸮ur.Csveamei⸮n⸮ievtumtp⸮vi⸮d⸮eil⸮oi⸮ruiusbeu⸮rs⸮l⸮ae⸮ai⸮t,⸮⸮oe⸮om
>   l⸮cdo⸮aesua⸮i⸮iin⸮⸮ab⸮e⸮vil⸮⸮u⸮u⸮an⸮fiiamssa. C⸮oi⸮tque petu⸮⸮ai⸮sptitmts⸮st⸮ril⸮u⸮tcsu⸮lie⸮t⸮nrnumuscg⸮oa⸮vu⸮vr⸮uci⸮l⸮g⸮oinm⸮msi⸮aq⸮ptb⸮tmn⸮i⸮rrn⸮oe⸮aerrdlsm.Ierbeu⸮gtslu,n⸮aisnl⸮ott
>   t.C⸮oi⸮tu⸮etu⸮⸮ai⸮sptit⸮ns⸮st⸮icu⸮s⸮

Here's the full code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTserial(2, 3); // RX, TX

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    BTserial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Communication with HC-05 successfully started.");
}

const char* BOOK_UPLOAD_START_TAG = "(__BOOK_UPLOAD_START__)";
const char* BOOK_UPLOAD_END_TAG = "(__BOOK_UPLOAD_END__)";
int tag_pos = 0;
char c;
bool is_uploading_book = false;

#define DELAY_SIZE 50
char delay_chars[DELAY_SIZE];
int update_count = 0;

void loop(){
    if (BTserial.available()) {
        c = BTserial.read();
        if (is_uploading_book) {
          Serial.write(c);
          if(update_count < DELAY_SIZE) {
            delay_chars[update_count] = c;
            update_count++;
          } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < (DELAY_SIZE - 1); i++) {
                delay_chars[i] = delay_chars[i + 1];
            }
            delay_chars[DELAY_SIZE - 1] = c;
            // Checking if the end tag is in the delay_chars
            for (int i = 0; i < (DELAY_SIZE - 1); i++) {
              if (check_tag_in_chars(delay_chars[i], BOOK_UPLOAD_END_TAG)) {
                tag_pos = 0;
                Serial.println("Uploaded");
                is_uploading_book = false;
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (check_tag_in_chars(c, BOOK_UPLOAD_START_TAG)) {
            tag_pos = 0;
            Serial.println("Starting");
            is_uploading_book = true;
          }
        }
    }

}

int check_tag_in_chars(char a, const char* TAG_STR) {
  if (a == TAG_STR[tag_pos])
    { tag_pos++; }
  else if (a == TAG_STR[0])
    { tag_pos = 1; }
  else
    { tag_pos = 0; }

  if (TAG_STR[tag_pos] == '\0') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Is there something that is overloading and torturing the Arduino? Are there any alternatives to go about the problem that will not create this problem?

NEW: It turns out that as I decrease the DELAY_SIZE value, the jibberish slowly starts to look normal. Somehow that for loop tortures the Arduino (and it's not so much the for loop but the check it's done in it)

NEW NEW: I tried looping a loop and it seems that making extensive loops overloads the Arduino and it starts jibberish. Is this normal or there's something with my Arduino?

NEW NEW NEW: If my void loop() looks like this:

```
void loop(){
   if (BTserial.available()) {
      c = BTserial.read();
      Serial.write(c);
      for (int i = 0; i < (DELAY_SIZE - 1); i++) {
         if (check_tag_in_chars(delay_chars[i], BOOK_UPLOAD_END_TAG)) {
            tag_pos = 0;
            Serial.println("Uploaded");
            is_uploading_book = false;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The problem of jibberish persists (the jibberish is less but it's still jibberish). The fact that I'm looping through the check_tag_in_chars 50 times every new character is torturing the Arduino.
I don't know what to do.

Comment: You didn't read my typo correction in your other correction.                 `delay_chars[DELAY_SIZE - 1] = c; }` should be `} delay_chars[DELAY_SIZE - 1] = c;`

Comment: @Majenko Sorry, fixed it (I got the delay_chars[DELAY_SIZE - 1] = c; out of the loop) but the problem stays. I did some debugging and the jibberish issue originates from the loop I've stated above.

Comment: @Juraj Please take a look at the full code.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is actually SoftwareSerial being a pile of rancid badger vomit.

Comment: or the BT module is on different baud rate

Comment: @Juraj How can that be? When the for loop is gone, everything works fine.

Comment: I just checked the HC-05 baud rate through AT, it's 9600.

Comment: If it helps, I has problems sending data through SoftwareSerial with the HC05 but receiving it was fine. Hardware serial never had this problem for me

Comment: "rancid badger vomit"? Is that a technical term? :)

Comment: I had a hard time trying to understand, why you use the delay_char array. I did not succeed. What is the intention of it? Why do you not check each character as it comes in from the bluetooth module? Do you need it for future uses? With the shift operation you have a good chance to create failure code. e.g. You shift only the chars until `DELAY_SIZE - 2` because of the `<` operator (you do not use a `<=`- Then you write over the last character in the array. That could be problematic;-).

Comment: I would also check the charset of the text you send over bluetooth. Is it UTF 8 or a Windows charset or another non ASCII code?